# How do I "unshare" files that are in a "shared" state with users on my computer (Windows 11)

Tags: windows, windows-11, users, profile

So a couple of days back I accessed files from my user profile from another user profile on my computer, ever since then some files were in shared state and I haven't been able to unshare them.

Comment: Insufficient information to understand the problem : How have you shared the files?

Comment: NET USE Z: /Delete for all drives Z:

Answer (score 0):

**Right-click the folder > Give access to > Remove access**

[image: Example]